# Why won't navbar fix to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works when I take out the check of window width. Once I add in a reference to the window width the code no longer works. I only want the navbar to become fixed on screen sizes smaller than 768px. I'm rusty with jQuery so help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(width) < 768) {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 567) {
        $('.navbar').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
      } else {
        $('.navbar').css('position', 'relative');
      }
    } else {
      $('.navbar').css('position', 'relative');
    }
  })

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(width) < 768) {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 567) {
        $('.navbar').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
      } else {
        $('.navbar').css('position', 'relative');
      }
    } else {
      $('.navbar').css('position', 'relative');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: use `width` only, not use `$(width)`

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that you're placing `width` within a jQuery object when this is not necessary. Just use `width` directly in the conditions:

```
if (width < 768)
```

That being said, your code can be DRY'd up and also improved through the use of CSS classes and media queries. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('fixed', $(this).scrollTop() > 567);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 2000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
```

Comment: When I use just ( width < 768 ) I receive a console error stating width is not defined

Comment: I can't replicate that: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/x8bpz7kf/. I'd strongly suggest you use the CSS approach, though.

Comment: I see, in the fiddle you declare the variable and I had removed it on my end. The console error is gone when I added it back. However in your fiddle I'm seeing the navbar become fixed no matter the screen size

Comment: Diving into this further it seems it works if loaded at a screen size, so if the browser loads in under 768px then the navbar is fixed but if I widen the screen it will remain fixed rather than returning back to relative